# Convert Javascript array into C# List

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, list

Following is my javascript array which I am passing from the server.

```
string request = @"[[1,""Name"",""Sam"",""20""],1,""Name"",""Ram"",""20""]]";
```

I want to convert it into a List of C# object.

```
public class UpdateData
    {
        public int RowID { get; set; }

        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        public string OldValue { get; set; }

        public string NewValue { get; set; }

    }
```

Is there an easy way to do that. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The easy way would be to use JSON... There are plenty of good librairies to help with serializing/deserializing (check Newtonsoft.Json)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get a List of Lists and then loop over it to form your List of UpdateData (using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/))

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<List<object>>>(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a Json parser.  Use Nuget to add one to your project:
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json